# Google Actions Re-certification requirements

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Do we need to re-certify a deployed skill if we edit Entities (eg: add synonyms) to Dialogflow or edit Types in case of using Actions Builder?

Essentially is there an "Update Live Skill" option similar to Alexa Skills Kit, where any published skill can be updated immediately when changes are limited to sample utterances within an intent or slot/entity values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes updates to the conversational model will require a redeploy, which will require a review if you go to the beta or production channels. Alpha releases do not require a review.

The [releases](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/releases) documentation may provide more information.